# How to pass .env file to docker image in a Go project?

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, environment-variables, dockerfile

My Go project heriarchy is this:

[image]

The main function:

```
func main() {
    path, _ := os.Getwd()
    err := godotenv.Load(filepath.Join(path, ".env"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading .env file")
    }
    server.Init()
}
```

Here is my `docker` file content:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS build-env
LABEL MAINTAINER "Amit Pal <amit.pal@fynchmobility.com>"
ENV GOPATH /go
WORKDIR /go/src
COPY . /go/src/gothamcity
RUN cd /go/src/gothamcity && go build .

FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk*
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /go/src/gothamcity/gothamcity /app

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "./gothamcity" ]
```

I ran the following command to build and run the docker image:

```
docker build -t gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/gothamcity:v1.0 .
docker run -ti gcr.io/miles-ee458/gothamcity:v1.0
```

I got the error:

> `2021/01/28 14:34:46 Error loading .env file`

What am I doing wrong here? How can I pass the .env file to docker image and execute it?

Also, isn't `COPY . /go/src/gothamcity` copy the entire project to docker image?

Comment: `.env` isn't a variable, it's a file. Your code looks for that file in the current working directory. Make sure it's in the container working directory.

Comment: @JimB Yes, I know this is a file but the idea is to copy the all environment variable from here to docker image?

Comment: You can set environment variables all you want, but the code is looking for a specific file, and you need to provide that file. If you only want to set environment variables, then don't use this code.

Comment: ok understood, Also is it only ccopying the `.go` files when I am using `COPY . /go/src/gothamcity` this line? It should suppose to copy the entire working directory

Comment: `COPY` copies files, it is not specific to `go` in any way.

Comment: Then it should copy the `.env` file

Comment: The runtime error is not coming from the build container which contains all the files.

Comment: @JimB It is coming from the container and after checking out the answer, It's not coming anymore

Comment: Yes, Then you have to understand what's the typo error and I should be knowing why "So-called modertor" closing the question. Don't you think it's nececssary?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`COPY . /go/src/gothamcity` only copies .env to build container. You have to explicitly copy it to your main container like this:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS build-env
LABEL MAINTAINER "Amit Pal <amit.pal@fynchmobility.com>"
ENV GOPATH /go
WORKDIR /go/src
COPY . /go/src/gothamcity
RUN cd /go/src/gothamcity && go build .

FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk*
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /go/src/gothamcity/gothamcity /app
COPY .env /app

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "./gothamcity" ]
```

Reason is that when you are saying "FROM alpine" this becomes a brand new blank container. That's how [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) are working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It did work for me. Why `COPY --from=build-env /go/src/gothamcity/gothamcity /app` is not ccopying the `.env` file?

Comment: because it copies only the application binary

Comment: I am having the same issue and it's working on my system but deployment on amazon ECS failed, no .env file copied.